# What is the "offset clause" in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The [latest Firecast](https://youtu.be/9sOT5VOflvQ), Doug Stevenson mentioned [`request.query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request.html#query), however, he only discussed **`request.query.limit`** and **`request.query.orderBy`** ([here is the timestamp](https://youtu.be/9sOT5VOflvQ?t=330)).
[The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request.html#query) names a third property, i.e. `request.query.offset`:

- `offset` - query offset clause.

In all the time I have been using Cloud Firestore, I have never seen the "*offset clause*".

Can someone explain what this offset clause is and how the `request.query.offset` property is implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That currently doesn't do anything.  Offset is currently only available to server SDKs (for example: [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#offset)); it's not an option in web and mobile client SDKs.  Since server SDKs always bypass security rules, there's nothing you can do with `request.query.offset` that would affect way rules would evaluate.

The reference to this should actually be removed from the documentation altogether.

Comment: Are no there plans for adding this to client SDKs (as you mentioned that it "should actually be removed from the documentation altogether")?

Comment: Not that I know of.